# HTML scroll left and right even though there is no elements on the right?

Tags: html, scroll, element

I can scroll left and right on this page even though there is no elements on the right can anyone please tell me why this is how to stop it and if this even happens for you? My browser size is 1920x1017px.

http://cannonmc.net/

Thanks, Luke.

Comment: You may want to start using tools like firebug on firefox. They can help you track down issues like this. You can download that as an add-on.

Answer (score 2):

Your values div is stretching. Add a float property to it

```
#values {
  float: left;
  left: 42.5%;
  position: relative;
  top: 75px;
}
```

The float will deal with the page breaking out. I do suggest working on the layout though. Centering content can be accomplished with better techniques that can be found here: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: I see what you're saying. But adding `float: left` to `#values`  breaks the layout of the child spans. I think the source of the problem is one level up at `.container`, where I focused my answer.

Comment: @Michael_B - no it does not. I cannot see your answer anymore, but media queries is not solving it. Other techniques need to be applied to get the required results.

Comment: @LukeDyte - i think you may want to look into some basics on centering content. Perhaps this will help you out: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: @Daniel, I must have entered a value incorrectly when I originally tested your code in Chrome Dev Tools, which was stacking the child elements. You are correct, it doesn't break the layout. +1